# Spring-Mongo-Data Update only allows one positional argument?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I have a data model with the following structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(''),
    strs: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId(''),
            nds: [
                {
                    _id: ObjectId(''),
                    title: ''
                },
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
```

Following query works perfectly fine in `mongo` shell:

```
mongo.update({_id: ObjectId(''), 'strs._id': ObjectId(''), 'strs.nds._id': ObjectId('')}, {$set: {'strs.$.nds.$.title': 'new-title'}})
```

I am trying to do the same in Spring Boot, I have written the following lines of code:

```java
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.addOperator(Criteria.where("id").is(id), 
    Criteria.where("strs.id").is(strsId), Criteria.where("strs.nds.id", ndsId));
Query query = new Query().addCriteria(criteria);
Update update = new Update();
update.set("strs.$.nds.$.title", title);
mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, MyModel.class);
```

But, this is not working as expected. It's saying that `mongo` cannot create a `title` field inside `[nds: {...}]`. So, I logged the queries `MongoTemplate` was generating, and it turns out that `MongoTemplate` was removing the second positional argument `$` from the query.

This was the generated query:

```
mongo.update({...}, {$set: {'strs.$.nds.title': 'new-title'}})
```

And this was the reason `mongo` was throwing an exception saying it cannot create a `title` field in an array.

Am I doing this wrong? Because `MongoTemplate` is generating an invalid query which is failing (obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is

```
update.set("strs.$[elmStr].nds.$[elmNds].title", title)
    .filterArray("elmStr._id", strsId)
    .filterArray("elmNds._id",ndsId);
```

And refer [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)