# org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot create field

Tags: mongodb, criteria

The update of Mongodb in Spring-boot throws exception and code is given below.

**Exception**

`org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Cannot create field`

**Update Query**

```
Query queryTwo = new Query();
queryTwo.addCriteria(Criteria.where("customerDetail.CID_18").exists(true));
Update update = new Update();
update.set("customerDetail.CID_18.activeDevices", "900");
```

The data in database is given below

```
{
    "_id" : "3c02a683-4601-419b-a598-9e9d8ce57fd0",
    "profileId" : "308",
    "name" : "resellerSent",
    "email" : "resellerSent@gmail.com",
    "customerDetail" : [ 
        {
            "CID_18" : {
                "customerId" : NumberLong(18),
                "activeDevices" : "0",
             
                "_class" : "com.demo.CustomerDetail"
            },
            "CID_2196" : {
                "customerId" : NumberLong(2196),
                "activeDevices" : "5",        
                "_class" : "com.demo.CustomerDetail"
            },
            "CID_2197" : {
                "customerId" : NumberLong(2197),
                "activeDevices" : "0",
                "_class" : "com.demo.CustomerDetail"
            }
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.demo.ResellerProfile"
}
```

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`, `version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'`

Comment: If you answer helps you please tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 2):

`customerDetail` is an array, So you need to use positional operator.

```
Query query=Query.query(Criteria.where("customerDetail.CID_18").exists(true));
Update update=new Update().set("customerDetail.$[].CID_18.activeDevices", "900");
return mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query,update,Users.class);
```

If you just add `$[]` for positional-all, the updation will be applied to **ALL** of the Objects which satisfy the update condition. If you need to update a particular object, then you can use `filterArray()` among with `set` [Filter array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61475499/spring-mongo-data-update-only-allows-one-positional-argument/61475616#61475616)

Refer [Positiaonal-all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/).